# Django login_required redirect with hash

Tags: django, redirect, django-authentication, http-redirect, django-login

I am trying to a access a page that has a `login_required` decorator without being logged in. This redirects me to `settings.LOGIN_URL` with `next?=original_page` in the query string.

The problem is that `original_page` is actually `original_page#hash`: `http://localhost:8000/?next=/ui/#/people/1234`

After I successfully login, I am redirected to the original page without the hash (i.e `http://localhost:8000/ui/` rather than `http://localhost:8000/ui/#/people/1234`). I know this is because the hash was never sent to the server and it is lost (discarded by the browser) on the login form `POST`.

What is the best way to solve this problem in Django? I found this: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-users/2PN-M_-sEGg but that dates back to 2009 and there does not seem to be consensus on a solution.

Comment: @Daniel-Roseman It isn't clear to me from the linked post, at what point in the request-reponse(-redirect) cycle the hash is available server side.

Comment: The point is that once next is properly urlquoted as '/ui/%23/people/1234', the entire string is available on the backend via `request.GET` and you can safely redirect to it.

Comment: @Daniel-Roseman By here: https://github.com/django/django/blob/0d912258921a442c48d5787228db2db5af7e8fa5/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py#L23 though the hash is not available to the backend. What string would I escape?